# WPF TextBox inheritance KeyDown does not trigger on space?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I have a class that inherits the wpf textbox and i have overridden the OnTextChanged, OnTextInput, OnKeyDown now to the funny part..

If i press any thing but **Space** all 3 events are triggered, but if i press **space** only the OnTextChanged is triggered? so why doesn't space count as a key or textinput?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event as the space is by default handled and therefore consumed by the framework.

Comment: might i ask why space is handled on preview and not in the normal way like the rest of the keys?, but yes ill give it a try.

Comment: @Petoj It is all contingent on the implementor whether the event is marked as handled or not. Theorizing is that it has something to do with textual layout as it also affects the Enter key when the TextBox.AcceptsReturn is marked as true.